# push segue causing break point

Tags: cocoa-touch, view, collections, breakpoints

hoepfully a simple fix. :)

I'm using a collection view with a push segue to a detailed view controller. When the cell is clicked in simulator the app crashes with a break point indicating at this part of the code:

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@end

@implementation DetailViewController

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];       //<--------- break point
    self.imageView.image = self.image;
}

@end
```

segue id etc is correct. So not at all sure why it shouldn't be working.

Any help on this as always is  appreciated. If you need further info let me know.

A.

edit:

.h file as follows:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *image;





@end
```

Comment: Any error info given?

Comment: nope. all that appears is: (lldb)

Comment: Can you include your DetailViewController.h file aswell please?

Comment: edit into the orriginal post above

Comment: Could you try running it with the line where you apply the image commented out. Or else synthesize your image property.

Comment: The build fails with the image property commented out, as for synthesizing the image - what would be the correct way to do this?

Comment: I've reconnected the segue from the orange icon on the view controller rather than from the cell itself to the detailed view controller, now the image is highlighted but no longer crashes - a step in the right direction... Still not sure how to make the segue reveal the detail as all identifiers are correct.

Comment: Try adding '@synthesize image' just inside your implementation. You can read up on what exactly this does here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Properties

Comment: No success, same issue.

Comment: See http://raywenderlich.com/6475/basic-security-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1

Comment: Post your `prepareForSegue:` method and error description's logs.